# How to get input with ":" in id by jQuery

Tags: jquery, getelementbyid

I am newbie in jQuery, but I try to learn it. 
Let's say I got input with id="userForm:id";
In javascript I can simple get id by:

```
var id = document.getElementById("userForm:id");
```

In jQuery I try:

```
var id = $('#userForm:id');
```

but then I get error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported
pseudo: id
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery thought of this problem already, and you only need to escape it, as detailed in the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and in more detail in the [jQuery FAQ](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F):

```
var id = $('#userForm\\:id');
```

The same is true of periods and other characters that are [valid ID characters](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#the-id-attribute) but have special CSS meaning.

As a general matter of style, I'd personally discourage you from using special characters (i.e. anything besides alphanumeric, underscores and slashes) in your HTML id properties, but there's certainly no technical reason why it can't be done.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
var id = $('#userForm\\:id');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xPufr/)

Answer (score 2):

according to http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

"you must escape the character with two backslashes: \\ "

`var id = $('#userForm\\:id');`

Answer (score 2):

you can also use :

```
$("form[id$='userForm:id']")
```

if your item is a form offcourse... Otherwise you should change the form in front of the square brackets.
This piece of code will look at each id of the forms in your page and check if it ends userForm:id
 see : http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

I haven't tested next piece of code, but i guess it should work:

```
$("form[id='userForm:id']")
```

This should only select the form with id userForm:id

Comment: Why do this when simply escaping the `:` character can be done?  I believe your way could require more DOM traversal depending on how many `form` elements are contained on the page.

Comment: @Sparky672 I agree, it is just another way of how it can be solved. But this solution is less desirable then other answers. (but in case the other answers would not work for some strange reason ... )

Comment: I'd give you a +1 for a well formed answer with supporting docs, but a -1 for recommending something less than ideal without any good reason to do so.  Net 0.